# implicit subpass dependency and barriers

Tags: vulkan

I must copy a color attachment into a buffer. Do I need an image memory barrier between the end of the render pass and the copy operation, to ensure visibility to the transfer?

The render pass has a single subpass with a single attachment. The `VkAttachmentDescription.finalLayout` differs from the `VkAttachmentReference.layout`, so an implicit subpass dependency with `dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` does indeed exists.

My confusion arises from the description of such implicit external dependency: it has a `dstAccessMask = 0` and `dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT`. Since the transfer stage happens before the end of pipe pseudostage, does it mean I need to specify a barrier? Or does the implicit dependency only affect operations in the render pass, so I need a barrier anyway? As a side question, what is the meaning of `0` as a source or destination access mask?

Validation layers do not report any issue either with or without a barrier, and the output is as expected, but I am not sure it is correct though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need a dependency between _______ and _______ in Vulkan.

Implicit dependency exists in the spec only for formal reasons. Without it you would not know when the layout transition happens when used e.g. with a Semaphore. But in practice the implicit dependency is no-op. Its `dst` half does not cover anything.

The meaning of `0` in access mask is "no access". E.g. `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT` stage does not read nor write anything, so the access flag accompanying it should be `0`.

Comment: Thanks, unsurprisingly, it makes perfect sense.